# Symfony not getting relation data in twig

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.8

Symfony get relational data:
I have ReservedOffer object and i am getting values like
    $reservedOffer->getOfferGroup()->getOffer()->getGood() i get like see image.[image]

But

```
$reservedOffer->getOfferGroup()->getOffer()->getGood()->getName() // Sony
```

but in twig if i write

```
reservedOffer.offerGroup.offer.good.name // i get ''
```

Why?
Any idea?

Comment: what is your query, DQL or querybuilder?

Comment: Hi @FrankB reservedOffer is a controller action parameter so get directly reservedOffer object.

Comment: In that case Symfony tries to load the reservedOffer object for you. Might be better to pass the id of the object as parameter and then load it yourself. If you dont understand me then ask me for an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So now i am selectindg data of associated tables also and my issue solves.
It worked by

```
public function findReservedOfferWithRelationData(ReservedOffer $reservedOffer)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('reservedOffer')
        ->select('reservedOffer, offerGroup, offer, good')
        ->join('reservedOffer.offerGroup', 'offerGroup')
        ->join('offerGroup.offer', 'offer')
        ->join('offer.good', 'good')
        ->where('reservedOffer.id = :id')
        ->setParameter('id', $reservedOffer->getId())
        ->getQuery()
        ->getOneOrNullResult();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set twig's `strict_variables` to `true` and you will see the error

```
# app/config/config.yml
twig:
    debug:            true
    strict_variables: true
```